Help identify the film in which a group of teenagers provides a hiding place for a runaway convict
It's an american film from late 80ties or 90ties about a group of boys who meet an adult criminal, I think a runaway convict. The convict hides in a shack in woods, 
which belongs to one of the boys, I think. They bring him food and he tells them stories. I am not 100% sure of the above facts, that's how I remember them.
There's one memorable scene though, which I think will help identify the film. On one occasion, one of the boys brings his girlfriend to the shack, and the convict tells her to take her top off (even after those years I remember the dialogue: the con said no girls are allowed there, she responded: what about those on the wall (there were posters with nude women), the con said: they're all naked), the boys do nothing, just sit paralysed, the girl manages to escape but she does not want to see her boyfriend ever again. I think it's a quite well-known movie, I just don't remember the title or any actors who were in it. I saw it on Polish tv some 15 years ago.

If you weren't so sure you'd seen it all that long ago, I would have said it was Mud. Either way, Jeff Nichols has a lot of explaining to do :-)


The Boys Club (1997)

Three teenage boys in small-town Southern Ontario are thrilled when
  Luke Cooper, a mysterious American fugitive with a gunshot wound in
  his leg, decides to crash their secret hideout. Luke tells them that
  he's a cop on the run from corrupt colleagues, and swears them to
  silence. As he recuperates, he becomes their buddy and confidante. By
  the time the boys realize Luke is not who he pretends to be, they're
  in way over their heads. ~ Edited from Wikipedia



Check out this clip for the scene you described. In fact, the whole movie's up on YouTube (in separate parts). The movie's Parents Guide section on IMDb also mentions the scene.

Spot on, rumandwrite! That's it. Thanks man.
